# Ruby unsupported protocol (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) on Debian/Linux

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, ruby-1.8, libssl

How to fix this error that happens on Debian Linux using ssl commands with ruby ?

/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unsupported protocol (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

I found the answer, Iḿ posting this as a reference for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change ruby version to at least 1.8.7-p358

I had this error after upgrading openssl libs from openssl_1.0.0h-1 (amd64) to openssl_1.0.1-4.

I'm on Debian testing wheezy.

Just use https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv to install ruby 1.8.7-p358. I had the standard ruby 1.8.7.352 from debian testing.

Hope it helps, if so comment !